# passing static method as parameter in Java

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

Hello I'm testing the class that has some validating methods and I've been wondering if there is a way to reduce the duplicated code.

```
@Test
void testCorrectEmailValidator() {
    List<String> correctEmails = Arrays.asList("test@test.com", "test123@test123.com", "test@test.com.in",
            "test.test2@test.com", "test.test2.test3@test.com", "TEST.2test@test.com");

    for (String email : correctEmails) {
        boolean isValid = UserCredentialsValidator.emailValidator(email);
        System.out.println("Email is valid: " + email + ": " + isValid);
        assertTrue(isValid);
    }
}

@Test
void testCorrectUsernameValidator() {
    List<String> correctUsernames = Arrays.asList("username", "123username", "username3", "user2name",
            "USERNAME", "USERNAME123", "123USERNAME123", "2uSERname33");

    for(String username : correctUsernames) {
        boolean isValid = UserCredentialsValidator.usernameValidation(username, userList);
        System.out.println("Username is valid:    " + username + "     : " + isValid);
        assertTrue(isValid);
    }
}
```

I also have validators for other fields such as username etc. I was thinking about implementing a helper method that would accept: tested credential as String, List but I've got a problem with last parameter - a validating method, not sure how to pass that.

The code i would like to replace with some method is the for loop.

Comment: extract the common code in methods, just as you would in regular code

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but why is there a list of items to validate?  If each item of the list is an edge case then give it a separate test, e.g., `validateUserNameWhenUserNameIsAllLowerCase()`.

Comment: the problem is that each for loop is using different UserCredentialsValidator validation method. I'm not sure how to extract it to the method that could be shared within tests

Comment: @javamat is `UserCredentialsValidator.usernameValidation(username, userList)` a typo? why does it take 2 arguments?

Comment: actually that method requires a list because it calls another method that searches for a user in a list and returns its index if present

Comment: A comment about such tests. I'd rather test/report and assert on *all* elements. If you fail on (say) the first element, you have *no* visibility on what other test cases you're going to fail on. Perhaps use streams to collect name+boolean indicating validity, log that, and finally assert on any failures in your stream...

Comment: @Stultuske it's not that simple, the methods have different signatures

Comment: You pass in the username _and_ the list? That feels like a security issue. I'd normally expect the validator to get the available users from some other (trusted) source.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko code that is not common isn't common code. The OP asked how to handle common code. The only 'duplicated code' in the code shown is: assertTrue(isValid); so a bit redundant to try and reduce duplicate code

Comment: Btw, you _could_ use function interfaces (assuming you're using Java8+) to pass methods but your code doesn't seem to have that much duplication (the only "duplicate" parts I see are the loop and the `assertTrue(isValid)` call - the printing statements use different strings so they are not exactly equal). I'm not sure rearranging the code you posted would help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid your tests are of low quality.

The problems that should be fixed immediately include

1. `UserCredentialsValidator.usernameValidation(username, userList);` The method shouldn't take the second argument. The place from where that list is retrieved should be concealed from the API consumer.
2. `List<String> correctEmails = Arrays.asList(...)` and `List<String> correctUsernames = Arrays.asList(...)` should be removed. You'd better make the tests parameterised with [`@ParameterizedTest`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.3.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/ParameterizedTest.html) and [`@ValueSource`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.3.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/ValueSource.html).
3. I'd rather remove the `System.out.println` statements. They make little sense in tests.

---

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"test@test.com", "test123@test123.com"})
void testUserEmailValidationWithValidUserEmailShouldPass(String validUserEmail) {
    boolean isValid = UserCredentialsValidator.emailValidator(validUserEmail);
    assertTrue(isValid);
}

@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"username", "123username"})
void testUserNameValidationWithValidUserNameShouldPass(String validUserName) {
    boolean isValid = UserCredentialsValidator.usernameValidation(validUserName);
    assertTrue(isValid);
}
```

Now there is nothing to reduce.

Comment: #3: After usernameValidation kicks off, it calls findUser method that takes a List<User> as parameter. I couldn't come up with a solution on how to pass that list to findUser method. I'm doing some console app and List<User> is static variable in Main class

Comment: @javamat Mate, you have to come up with another one. Honestly, your approach sucks. A global public static variable is never a good sign. Restrict the scope of that variable so it is accessible only from a few places (validation, user retrieval). Obtain the list within `usernameValidation`, don't pass it to the method.

Comment: I understand. Would it be a good idea to create a class UserList that's just storing list of users ? By doing it this way I could remove the second parameter and in findUser method access the list with UserList class

Comment: @javamat yes, that would make sense. It could be a class `UserStorage`/`UserRepository` (a nice Spring-inspired name) that encapsulates that list and provides some specific list-related operations needed.

Answer (score 0):

Fact that you're struggling to test is indicating a *design smell*.

Its good time for you to explore [strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) here.

Basically you **main code** would look something like

```
interface IValidator {
     boolean isValid(List<String> yourDataToBeValidated);
}
```

Now create multiple validator classes for different fields like email, username etc.

```
class EmailValidator implements IValidator {
      boolean isValid(List<String> yourDataToBeValidated){
         //Email specific validations goes here
      }
}
```

You can create more validators as you need on the go.

Now **in your unit tests** create `new EmailValidator()` or `new UsernameValidator()` and pass your `emailIds` or `usernames` to be `isValid()` method, something like below :

```
    boolean isValid = new EmailValidator().isValid(Arrays.asList("test@test.com", "test123@test123.com");
    assertTrue(isValid);
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue at hand.

Comment: @Stultuske op has followed bad design and hence its difficult to test. I am just suggesting an approach which is easier to maintain and test.

Comment: no, his tests aren't the problem at all, they work. it's having the (almost) duplicate code in one spot, instead of spread over different test methods he's trying to accomplish. Doesn't mean you're wrong about the approach, though.

Comment: `interface IValidator(){` is not Java syntax

Answer (score 0):

As I already stated in my comment to your question, I'm not sure rearranging your code would help much. However, as a comparision here's a Java8+ version which uses a common method:

```
@Test
void testCorrectEmailValidator() {
  List<String> correctEmails = Arrays.asList("test@test.com", "test123@test123.com", "test@test.com.in",
          "test.test2@test.com", "test.test2.test3@test.com", "TEST.2test@test.com");

  testValidator( "Email", correctEmails , email -> UserCredentialsValidator.emailValidator(email) );
}

@Test
void testCorrectUsernameValidator() {
  List<String> correctUsernames = Arrays.asList("username", "123username", "username3", "user2name",
        "USERNAME", "USERNAME123", "123USERNAME123", "2uSERname33");

  //I don't know where userList does come from but it would need to be final to be used here
  testValidator( "Username", correctUsernames, username -> UserCredentialsValidator.usernameValidation(username, userList) );
}

void testValidator( String name, List<String> data, Predicate<String> validator) {
  for( String element : data ) {
    boolean isValid = validator.test( element );
    System.out.println( name + " is valid:    " + element + "     : " + isValid);
    assertTrue(isValid);
  }
}
```

In that particular case both approaches would be 23 lines long while the second one might be easier to reuse but harder to understand and less flexible (e.g. if you'd need to pass additional parameters etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterized tests:

```
static Stream<String> emailsSource() {
    return Stream.of("test@test.com", "test123@test123.com", "test@test.com.in",
        "test.test2@test.com", "test.test2.test3@test.com", "TEST.2test@test.com");
}

@Test
@MethodSource("emailsSource")
void testCorrectEmailValidator(String email) {
    boolean isValid = UserCredentialsValidator.emailValidator(email);
    assertTrue(isValid);
}
```

Repeat for usernameSource etc. IMHO, this is sufficient to eliminate duplicities.

However if you want to go further and generalize it, use method references. I wouldn't recommend it though.

```
static Stream<Pair<String,Predicate<String>>> allSources() {
    return Stream.of(
        Pair.of("test@test.com", UserCredentialsValidator::emailValidator),
        Pair.of("username", UserCredentialsValidator::usernameValidationOneArg), // like usernameValidation but with argument userList fixed
        ...
    );
}

@Test
@MethodSource("allSources")
void testAll(Pair<String,Predicate<String>> p) {
    String s = p.getLeft();
    Predicate<String> test = p.getRight();
    boolean isValid = test.apply(email);
    assertTrue(isValid);
}
```

Comment: I've never used `@MethodSource` before, should it refer exclusively to a static method?